# Open .odg file in GIMP

Tags: images, libreoffice, gimp

My colleague sent me an .odg file with text boxes and different images.

I would like to work with it in GIMP rather than in LibreOffice, but GIMP won't recognize the format.

I tried exporting it as a .svg and as a .pdf, but in both occasions the text layers and images were combined into a single combined layer.

How can I change the format to something readable with GIMP without losing the layer information?

Comment: Ideally you would convert to `.xcf`, the GIMP native format, but I have not found a converter for this, nor to other formats that support layers. Have you tried copying and pasting from one program to the other? It's a wild guess, but it may work.

Comment: @AFH that was a good suggestion, but the format gets lost. If there is no other way I guess I will copy paste every element individually and then retype the text boxes, but it is certainly not ideal.

Comment: @Jsevillamol in that case i recommend adding an extra step after you export to the `.pdf`. Open the `.pdf` file in inkscape which is also vector tool and exports directly to gimp `.xfc`. It will be easier to work with the elements there.

Comment: If you open the `.odg` file in LO Draw, then you should be able to copy the text fields individually and import into separate GIMP layers from there, which will save retyping. But are you sure you want to use GIMP to edit the whole file? Isn't it better to save the images (eg slide master background), edit these in GIMP, then update them in the `.odg`? This should maintain all the formatting and layout, some of which is bound be lost in any attempt to import into GIMP layers.